# Mongodb aggregation pipeline on distinct values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, distinct

Let's say sample data in teams collection like this-

```
db.teams.insertOne({id: 0, team: "Mavs", position: "Guard", points: 31})
db.teams.insertOne({id: 1, team: "Mavs", position: "Guard", points: 22})
db.teams.insertOne({id: 2, team: "Rockets", position: "Center", points: 19})
db.teams.insertOne({id: 3, team: "Rockets", position: "Forward", points: 26})
db.teams.insertOne({id: 4, team: "Rockets", position: "Forward", points: 29})
db.teams.insertOne({id: 5, team: "Cavs", position: "Guard", points: 33})
```

Using mongo query, how can I get results like-

```
[
{team: "Mavs", ids: [0, 1]},
{team: "Rockets", ids: [2, 3, 4]},
{team: "Cavs", ids: [5]}
]
```

Any idea or solution?

Comment: Have you checked out [$push](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/)? It is nearly the most basic use case.

Comment: check out $group and $push

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
db.teams.aggregate([{$group: {_id: {team: "$team"}, ids: {$addToSet: "$id"}}}])
```

refer:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#mongodb-group-grp.-addToSet

Comment: Excellent! only correction is - '{ }' should be replaced with '[ ]' at one place. like-
db.teams.aggregate([ $group: {_id: {team: "$team"}, ids: {$addToSet: "$id"}} ])

Comment: yep, I'm missing the '[ ]' syntax =))